# Simulation of Electrical drives using Dymola

Tags: modelica, dymola

Is there anyone working with Dymola in the field of Electrical drives simulations?

Comment: Although this is a question, it isn't a specific question.  I'm sure the answer is yes.  Can you state a specific code problem you are having?

Answer (score 1):

You can find a very nice implementation here: [[Haumer](https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/Modelica.Electrical.Machines.html)].
Read also the publications from this group: There are a lot of improvements on this approach. The advantage of this approach is the funtamental physics/symmetries of all types of machines.